# Converting Single Json Object to Json Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

i am calling coincap.io single JSON object

```
{"altCap":282255454377.94916,"bitnodesCount":11508,"btcCap":149160858393,"btcPrice":8830.18849156212,"dom":63.86,"totalCap":431416312770.94904,"volumeAlt":709387849.4057536,"volumeBtc":1253729369.908587,"volumeTotal":1963117219.314342}
```

and i want to be array like

```
[{"altCap":282255454377.94916,"bitnodesCount":11508,"btcCap":149160858393,"btcPrice":8830.18849156212,"dom":63.86,"totalCap":431416312770.94904,"volumeAlt":709387849.4057536,"volumeBtc":1253729369.908587,"volumeTotal":1963117219.314342}]
```

This is my main php class

```
Class Second {
 private function request($url)
     {


         $curl = curl_init();

         curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
             CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
             CURLOPT_URL => $url,
             CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Agent'
         ));

         return curl_exec($curl);

         curl_close($curl);

     }

     public function jsonCache($ctime)
     {
         global $request_type, $purge_cache, $limit_reached, $request_limit;

         $cache_file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/data/global.json';
         $expires    = time() - $ctime;

         if (!file_exists($cache_file))
             die("Cache file is missing: $cache_file");

         if (filectime($cache_file) < $expires || file_get_contents($cache_file) == '' || $purge_cache && intval($_SESSION['views']) <= $request_limit) {

             $query = 'https://coincap.io/global';

             $api_results  = $this->request($query);

             $json_results = $api_results;

             if ($api_results && $json_results)
                 file_put_contents($cache_file, $json_results);


         } else {

             $json_results = file_get_contents($cache_file);
             $request_type = 'JSON';
         }

         return $json_results;
     }

}

?>
```

any idea how to put it in square brackets?
already using the same PHP class for an array and working fine
but I want this single object to have square brackets written in JSON file

Comment: Why? It is valid JSON. Do you want JSON, or do you want an array?

Comment: Where do you actually decode the JSON for use in PHP?

Comment: @AbraCadaver He doesn't, he just stores and serves it as is...

Comment: @AbraCadaver $data = json_decode($Second->jsonCache('300'), 2); tried $data = json_decode($Second, TRUE,), nothing happened

Comment: Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in....... @AbraCadaver

Comment: `$data = array(json_decode($Second->jsonCache('300'), 2)); `

Comment: You can post an answer below on what solved your issue. But this is not a forum, therefore we do not append [SOLVED] to the question title.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs got it

Answer (score 0):

In your return statement, just concatenate the brackets

```
return '['.$json_result.']';
```

Comment: Never manually form JSON, especially when it is not necessary.

Comment: The only other way is to decode, wrap in an array and then encode again.

Comment: That was the guys question ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: And this is a bad solution. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @JayBlanchard: If this is never used as an array/object in PHP then seems like overkill to decode it.

Comment: Why go about automated ways when doing it yourself is perfectly valid?

Comment: I agree @AbraCadaver. I just don't understand why valid JSON would need to have this done.

Comment: In this case it might be OK @Pazuzu156, but it is easy to make mistakes when manually encoding JSON. Too easy.

Comment: Be that as it may, and I agree that it's pointless to make his json object into an array, it's the result he wanted without having to decode, add to a new array, and re-encode